# Showing wordpress theme demo at front end

Tags: themes, users, front-end, previews

i am an wordpress developer and i am currently in a project in which i have 15 wordpress responsive themes and can be downloaded by users of my site.

In this , i want the feature to show the user previewing the theme. How can set this feature in front end. Any help! Thanks for advance.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-theme-preview/

Answer (score 0):

just setup another wordpress site for demo of your theme will be ok.

Comment: How would that work with a varying amount of themes?

Answer (score 0):

A better option will be to keep all the themes that you want to display as gallery on a page and have a individual links that will display preview of each theme. Use the plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-theme-demo-bar/ to achieve this functionality.

Found a nice tutorial here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-a-theme-demo-bar-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you subharanjan for your efforts and time. I will try and use above plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody wanders by: this problem does not exist anymore. Previewing themes is a WordPress core functionality now. Actually, you can even live customize a new theme ([docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/), [easy how to](http://www.themelab.com/preview-wordpress-theme-live-site/)).